# color with gradient shapefile in r considering specific value

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, shapefile

I have state provinces, but I need to color them considering the value I have related to every province.

data_char is made by two columns: A (provinces) and B (values)

```
      A                 B   
"province_A"          0.6
"province_B"          0.9
"province_Z"          0.7
```

state is made by different columns. That one I want to use for the join is called "provinces".

```r
state <- shapefile(file.shp)

state_n <- merge(state, data_char, key = "province")
```

so in the shp file I want to have

```
  A                 B.data_char   
"province_A"          0.6
"province_B"          0.9
"province_Z"          0.7
```

After that, I want to plot the value for every province, as a gradient using ggplot or other function. I'd like to have  a fill = "B.data_char".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your question is more likely to be answered well if you can help us to reproduce a specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to an `sf` object, then join the data together, then plot the data with `scale_fill_gradient`. Here, I'll provide some sample data using US states, but I'll rename them like your province data.

**Sample Data**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(maps)

provinces <- sf::st_as_sf(
  map(
    "state",
    fill = TRUE,
    plot = FALSE,
    regions = c("washington", "oregon", "idaho")
  )
) %>% 
  rename(province = ID) %>% 
  mutate(province = c("province_A", "province_B", "province_Z"))

data.char <- read.table(text = "province                 values   
province_A          0.6
province_B          0.9
province_Z          0.7", header = T)
```

**Plotting**

```
left_join(provinces, data.char, by = "province") %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = values)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "seagreen3", high = "darkgreen")
```

**Output**

[image]

*Convert .shp to sf object*

If you need to convert the shapefile to an `sf` object, then I usually do the following, but you might need to change the projection (i.e., `crs`) for your area. If so, then you can skip the steps above, and go straight to the plotting section (i.e., with the `left_join`).

```
state <- raster::shapefile("file.shp") %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(crs = 4326)
```